# How to Select File on android using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-afilechooser

I use this code to use Intent to select any type of file and get it's path in my application

```
    //this when button click
public void onBrowse(View view) {
    Intent chooseFile;
    Intent intent;
    chooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    chooseFile.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    chooseFile.setType("file/*");
    intent = Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Choose a file");
    startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;
    String path     = "";
    if(requestCode == ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE)
    {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        String FilePath = getRealPathFromURI(uri); // should the path be here in this string
        System.out.print("Path  = " + FilePath);
    }
}

public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String [] proj      = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor       = getContentResolver().query( contentUri, proj, null, null,null);
    if (cursor == null) return null;
    int column_index    = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

the problem when the file browser open i can't select a file it seems like it's not enable when i pressed on a file nothing happend so what is the wrong with this code
i upload a screenshot from my android mobile 
[image](https://s28.postimg.org/gb5h2unf1/Screenshot_20161217_002712.png)
 
Thanks in advance

Comment: `file/*` isn't a valid mime type. What kinds of files do you accept? Why are you trying to get a path from a file? What do you want to do with the file you accept?

Comment: I have a project of data structure that I want to get a file that has hundreds of queries the type of a file is .txt

Comment: I upload an image from my android app i can't select any kind of file so what should i do to make it work i try this too file/*.txt but not work @ianhanniballake

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> the type of a file is .txt

Then use `text/plain` as a MIME type. As Ian Lake noted in a comment, `file/*` is not a valid MIME type.

Beyond that, delete `getRealPathFromURI()` (which will not work). There is no path, beyond the `Uri` itself. You can read in the contents identified by this `Uri` by calling `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver`, and you can get a `ContentResolver` by calling `getContentResolver()` on your `Activity`.

Answer (score 11):

Change the line :

```
chooseFile.setType("file/*");
```

to

```
chooseFile.setType("*/*");
```

This will help you choose any type of file.

Comment: @kaushik I want to fetch inly doc files [like .pdf .txt .doc .docs].Please help

Comment: Change to: chooseFile.setType( "*/*");   without the space between / to *